# how to send send emoji to bot in telethon

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

Trying to send emoji to bot in telegram using this code

```
text_found = None
messagetosend = ''
with TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats = botname))
    async def my_event_handler(event):
        global text_found
        text_found = event.raw_text
        await client.disconnect()
   # client(functions.messages.StartBotRequest(bot = botname, peer = '@user', start_param = emoji.emojize(':House Building:')+' Мой Кабинет'))
    client(functions.messages.StartBotRequest(bot = botname, peer = '@user', start_param = messagetosend))
    client.run_until_disconnected()

print(text_found)
```

but receive error- Start parameter invalid (caused by StartBotRequest) how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very likely a restriction from Telegram's API itself. The error is not created by Telethon, meaning it can't be "fixed", but there are workarounds.

You can either encode the text into something else (perhaps the unicode values, or Python's unicode escape encoding), or use `send_message` instead (but then you can't set the `peer`):

```py
client.send_message(botname, messagetosend)
```

(Don't forget to `await` the above call if you use it within an `async` context.)

Comment: yes just sending message is working. Thank you!